# Why the Magento 2 "Collection Data" Cache is used not for all entities?

Tags: magento2, cache

In my practice I've never really faced with situation that it was needed to clean the collection cache. It is strange)
I checked and detected that the magento uses the [collection cache](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html#config-cli-subcommands-cache-clean-over) only for 4 entities:

```
website
store_group
store
category
```

These entities uses for their collections the virtual types based on

```
\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Cache
```

which in turn uses `\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Collection` for defining the cache type - `collection`.

You can find the all SQL-queries which used (after md5 tranformation) as cache keys - see the `fetchAll` method.

And these SQL-queries only to tables which related to entities listed above.

Why doesn't magento use the collection cache for other entities, such as products or CMS-pages?

When should we use the collection cache for own custom entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't magento use the collection cache for other entities, such as products or CMS-pages?

Doesn't need to. website, store_group and store are used in a lot of other logic but rarely change.  The category entity is an interesting one.  I can only assume because of the generation of category tree.  So from a performance point of view. Although in my opinion is the one that stands out from the rest.  Products are likely to change.  CMS pages are single item collections.

> When should we use the collection cache for own custom entities?

If what you implement is likely to impact performance (so a single large collection within a controller and/or rendered block logic) but contains data that won't change very often.